# Infinite series with prime number

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I know the $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\text{Prime[$n$]}}$ does not converge, but what about the  following series?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{Prime[Prime[$n$]]}}$$ 
(Where $\text{Prime[$n$]}$ is the $n$th prime number.)

I ran some calculation on Mathematica, but I am not sure in the answer gets very close to 1. 
Can anyone help with that?

NB: I an not a professional mathematician. I am just an amateur.

Comment: What is Prime[Prime[n]] ?

Comment: The $n$-th prime is asymptotically $n\log n$, so the $p_n$-the prime is asymptotically $(n\log n)\log (n\log n) \geqslant n(\log n)^2$, and that means the sum converges.

Comment: Just wanted to say: even though I voted to mark as a duplicate, I think this question is a really good one--so don't take it personally or anything; finding if a question has been asked previously is very difficult on this site.